# SQL Azure throttling information

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How do I see if an SQL Azure database is being throttled?
I want to see data like: what percentage of time  it was throttled, the count of throttles, the top reasons of throttles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711868/azure-performance/13091125#13091125

Throttling is the least of your troubles.  If you need performance then you would be best served to build your own DB servers using VM roles.  I found that the performance of these is vastly improved over SQL Azure.  For fault tolerance you can provision a primary and a failover in a different VM in a different region if necessary.  Make sure that the DB resides on the local drive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that information is currently available.  However, the team does share reasons why you could be throttled and how to handle it ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394106.aspx#throttling)).